# Is there a workaround for the form dimensions forced to be <= screen dimensions limitation of windows forms applications?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I once wrote an app that could display photographs.  I am trying to re-write it in Visual Studio with C# and give it new features.   The application I am writing now does use scroll bars to facilitate viewing an over-sized image. The previous app would fill the form area with the image and you could drag and hold the mouse to move it about on the screen.  If the image was bigger than the screen you'd simply move it about to view previously hidden areas.  By making the form the same size as the image it was very elegant way of dealing with the 'problem' of viewing an image that is bigger than your screen dimensions.

The advantage of this over putting the image inside a statically re-sizable form with scroll-bars was that the image would fill the available screen space, and if the next image in the sequence (it is a browser that allows you to cycle through images) was small, the image app would only take up as much space as the image.  You could easily move it to one side.  You didn't have to manually resize the form that was displaying it to make room for other applications.

I am unable to implement the same feature in the new app because Visual Studio won't let me dynamically re-size the form to be taller or wider than the screen.

Does anyone know of a plugin or workaround to override this limitation?

I am open to suggestions to achieve the same goal, but I would still like to know if this limitation can be turned off,  perhaps with a plugin or in code somehow.   Below is a link to a video of the previous incarnation of the app,  demonstrating the behavior I want to acheive by being able to set the form size larger than the screen dimensions...

**Edit:** A demo of the the previous application - and the behavior I want to implement...

http://youtu.be/J16EwuozvbQ

Comment: Why don't you use scrollbars on your picture container?

Comment: That is a solution but it is MUCH less elegant than how the previous incarnation of the app worked.  I could literally drag the app around as if it were a picture.   I would rather have it work the way I want to than concede to using scroll bars.

Comment: How did you drag the app around when it was out of the visible part of the screen?

Comment: Using the parts of the app that were not outside the visible part of the screen.  You'll see when I include the video link.

Comment: You are using a class library to not have to deal with the details of implementing a UI on windows.  Which exposes you to the preferences of what the class library writers considered "reasonable".  Winforms puts few obstacles in the way, lots of things you tweak by overriding WndProc().  But not this one, they put their foot down.  There is absolute no way you can create a window that's larger than the screen.  That busy-body code is private and can't be hacked.  A completely sensible and honorable choice, but you'll disagree about that.  So don't use Winforms.

Comment: You are right. I will disagree.  I'll look into alternatives to winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having a form bigger than the screen is not what you should search for. You can play with the position (top/left) coordination of the image on the form. You can have coordinates with minus values, so you will give the impression to the end user that he browse the image boundaries that's outside of the screen dimension.

Comment: This,  or what I think you are describing - have the form's top,left,height,width change dynamically to give the appearance that the form is bigger than the screen - might be what I end up doing if there is no way to turn the limitation off.

Comment: Yes, or you go for scrolling option, you may search for a way to hide out the scrolls.

Comment: As it happens I have already got the app working with scroll bars.  I just want to take it to this next level which I think makes it more usable. See the video - http://youtu.be/J16EwuozvbQ

Comment: Yeah, I see that you can move the image around as well

Comment: You may consider using DirectX within your app. It may give you better options esp. for graphics work.

Comment: I'll look into what I can do with directx.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can create a `Form` with a `PictureBox`.

[image]

Then change the `AutoScroll` property of the Form (or the container of the `PictureBox`, if applicable) to `true`.

And then change the `SizeMode` property of the `PictureBox` to `AutoSize`.

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: In this I get a 'letterbox' to view the picture in.  In the app I want to create I get the image going all the way to the edge of the screen,  and if I want to see what's beyond the edge I just move the entire form the other way.  In this mode the entire screen is my 'letterbox' instead of having to have it be a form within the screen.